# Python class constructor with default arguments

Tags: python, oop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Least Astonishment” in Python: The Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument)

Can anyone explain the following strange behaviour?

I have the following class:

```
class Zoo:
    def __init__(self,alist=[]):
        self.animals = alist

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.animals)

    def add(self,a):
        self.animals.append(a)
```

and when I do the following,

```
In [38]: z=Zoo()
In [39]: z.add(2)
In [40]: z.add(23)
In [41]: len(z)
Out[41]: 2

In [42]: z2=Zoo()

In [43]: len(z2)
Out[43]: 2
```

Why is z2.animals not an empty list?

Thanks, Matthias

Comment: Maybe he did not know what to search for? Sometimes it's hard to come up with the right search terms, if you don't know the terms.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are mutating the default argument in your constructor (you are just copying a reference to the same list into each of your instances).  You can fix this as follows:

```
class Zoo:
    def __init__(self,alist=None):
        self.animals = alist or []

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.animals)

    def add(self,a):
        self.animals.append(a)
```

Answer (score 7):

The default argument list is the same object for all instances, hence assigning it to a member just assigns a reference to the same object.

here's an example:

```
>>> class foo():
...   def __init__(self, x = []):
...       print id(x)
... 
>>> x = foo()
140284337344168
>>> y = foo()
140284337344168
>>> z = foo()
140284337344168
```

you can see that `x` is the same object in all instances.

Comment: great illustration of a confusing and common misconception!